# Fingerprint scanning using FIDO UAF for mobile application

Tags: java, android, fingerprint, scanning, fido-u2f

I am member of FIDO alliance. I'm working on one Mobile application where for security purpose I would like to include fingerprint scanning. I have referred to all documents available / provided by FIDO UAF for user management.. and that is exactly what I wish to include in my application. Basically I 'm looking for API / SDK / Available document for development.

And also I have few questions to come up with

1) It is possible to have a fingerprint scanning feature with the help of FIDO alliance. ? With the help of API Provided if any,
2) Does Fido alliance is implement in below android version 23.
3) Is there any documentation which can be referred to develop fingerprint scanning feature. If any API or SDK is available for FIDO UAF in android studio then can you provide me ?

Comment: You need Hardware for that. Many android phone dont have as in screen.

Answer (score 3):

IdentityX has been made for a really excellent Demo for the mobile client side of FIDO UAF and the related server. Here is the official guide for how to implement it.
http://daoninc.github.io/fido-integration/#overview

Also, you can check the souce code on github.
https://github.com/daoninc/fido-android-rp-app

I am a FIDO developer in China. Glad to exchange our opinions.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can find helpful information about FIDO and Passkeys at [passkeys.com](https://passkeys.com) .I used it and it took me no time to implement FIDO into my website. I think their method described there is the easiest and detailed one out there. I assume most of your questions have answers there.

Here are some samples I found at github https://github.com/OwnID/samples